# Snowflake Add new column with unique random value for each record

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a data set as below

```
Name      Email            date
john    john@aol.com.    2020-09-01
kevin    kevin@att.net.  2020-09-08
john.   john@aol.com.    2020-09-08
```

this dataset will be updated weekly with new data and date when the data is loaded.

I need to add another column, Anonymous_id : which is a unique value for each row. This should be random alphanumerical column with len>=6

The reason is we may have same email and name for different dates. so we want to use Anonymous_id column as primary key.

Remember this table will be loaded with data each week once.

```
Name    Email          Date          Anonymous_id
John   john@aol.com    2020-09-01.    123ax56
kevin. kevin@att.net.   2020-09-08.   245xd67
John.   john@aol.com.  2020-09-08.    456yt23
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function RANDSTR(  ,  ) that can produce a random 6 character string.  It doesn't guarantee uniqueness.   Using UUID_STRING() would give you better odds of producing unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a number to a string:

```
 select lpad(row_number() over (order by random()), 6, '0')
```

This produces a number and will work up to 999,999 rows.  It can easily be extended for larger numbers of rows.

That said, I would suggest that you just use the number and not a string for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use numbers instead of strings. I would just use `row_number()`

```
create table new_table as

select name, email, date, row_number() over (order by name, email, date) as anonymous_id
from old_table;
```

Down the line, this also allows you to look at the most recent email address per name since you can simply add `anonymous_id=1` in the where clause when you query this new_table